# Google reCAPTCHA issue while loading same popup twice

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-modal, recaptcha

I am trying to load Google reCAPTCHA in popup. First time it is load properly but while i it is closed and load again it is not loaded.

single page having two link both link are displaying in same popup. First time Google reCAPTCHA load perfectly.

[image]
Second time Google reCAPTCHA not loading.
[image]
code for Google reCAPTCHA

```
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="result123"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

     if(yourGlobalVariable==000)
     {
       console.log("call first time");

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/nitin/test1',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(msg) {
              $( "#result" ).empty().append( msg );
              console.log(msg);
            }
        });     
    }

    if(yourGlobalVariable==111)
    {
       console.log("call second time");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/nitin/test1',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(msg) {
               $( "#result123" ).empty().append( msg );
               console.log(msg);
            }
      });
   }
```

Comment: what is this result div with result and result123 id?

Comment: You can just use result only instead.

Comment: @Bluetree not working for set same result id for both. But I got the msg data both ajax call but not load in second time.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the output of this console.log(msg) in your first and second load

Comment: first time 

<div data-callback="enableBtn" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Ld6txMTAAAAAEN10JIKdk2jZAOUYJdyp1DjG9Y1" style="transform-origin:0 0;-webkit-transform-origin:0 0;">
            </div>

<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>

Comment: The second time?

Comment: Are there any errors showed  in console?

Comment: not show any error msg

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if it works

Comment: Is this a modal?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158376/discussion-between-bluetree-and-nitin-godhani).